# Named shutting down

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, vps

My DNS goes down periodically.

```
named[1482]: shutting down
named[1482]: stopping command channel on 127.0.0.1#953
named[1482]: stopping command channel on ::1#953
named[1482]: no longer listening on 127.0.0.1#53
named[1482]: no longer listening on xx.xx.179.58#53
named[1482]: no longer listening on xx.xx.134.252#53
named[1482]: no longer listening on xx.xx.196.243#53
named[1482]: exiting
```

Once per minute watchdog checking services

```
watchdog[5802]: Checking Cron
watchdog[5802]: Checking SMTP
watchdog[5802]: Checking DNS
watchdog[5802]: DNS done (ERR)
watchdog[5802]: Checking HTTP
watchdog[5802]: Checking POP3
watchdog[5802]: Checking MySQL
```

Restarts DNS

```
watchdog[5802]: Restarting DNS
named[5829]: bla bla bla...
watchdog[5802]: Checking DNS
watchdog[5802]: DNS done (OK)
```

After 2 seconds

```
named[1482]: shutting down
named[1482]: stopping command channel on 127.0.0.1#953
named[1482]: stopping command channel on ::1#953
named[1482]: no longer listening on 127.0.0.1#53
named[1482]: no longer listening on xx.xx.179.58#53
named[1482]: no longer listening on xx.xx.134.252#53
named[1482]: no longer listening on xx.xx.196.243#53
named[1482]: exiting
```

Watchdog restarts it and so on...

After a few loops my VPS goes down... I have to reboot it.

Such a problem I have each 3-5 days.

dmseg is empty.

There are no other information in the 'messages' log file.
Here is the named restart log:

```
watchdog[5802]: Restarting DNS
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: starting BIND 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.2 -u named
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: built with '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--with-libtool' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-ipv6' '--with-pic' '--disable-static' '--disable-openssl-version-check' '--with-dlz-ldap=yes' '--with-dlz-postgres=yes' '--with-dlz-mysql=yes' '--with-dlz-filesystem=yes' '--with-gssapi=yes' '--disable-isc-spnego' '--with-docbook-xsl=/usr/share/sgml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets' '--enable-fixed-rrset' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS= -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' 'CPPFLAGS= -DDIG_SIGCHASE'
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: ----------------------------------------------------
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: available at https://www.isc.org/support
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: ----------------------------------------------------
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: adjusted limit on open files from 1024 to 1048576
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: found 8 CPUs, using 8 worker threads
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: using up to 4096 sockets
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/named.iscdlv.key'
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: listening on IPv4 interface lo:1, xx.xx.179.58#53
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: listening on IPv4 interface lo:2, xx.xx.134.252#53
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: listening on IPv4 interface eth0, xx.xx.196.243#53
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: sizing zone task pool based on 57 zones
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: using built-in DLV key for view _default
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file '/var/named/dynamic/managed-keys.bind'
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: Warning: 'empty-zones-enable/disable-empty-zone' not set: disabling RFC 1918 empty zones
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: 127.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: 254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: 2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: 100.51.198.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: 113.0.203.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: 255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: D.F.IP6.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: 8.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: 9.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: A.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: automatic empty zone: 8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: command channel listening on ::1#953
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.com/IN: loaded serial 2013050600
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.net/IN: loaded serial 2013041201
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040200
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050801
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013041500
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040200
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013041500
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013060401
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050300
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040201
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013032584
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone isp.xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013032501
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone webmail.xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013032902
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040209
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013051001
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013051001
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013041500
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013041500
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050600
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013060401
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013060401
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050600
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050701
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013060401
Jun 14 14:46:11 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013060401
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050701
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050700
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040500
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040900
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050700
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050801
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050801
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013041500
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013050801
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013041500
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013053101
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013051001
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.su/IN: loaded serial 2013040401
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040900
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013040400
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: managed-keys-zone ./IN: loaded serial 4011
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: running
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone webmail.xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013032902)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013051001)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040200)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013032584)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050600)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013060401)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.net/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013041201)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013041500)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040201)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040200)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone isp.xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013032501)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040209)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040900)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013041500)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013041500)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050701)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013051001)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013060401)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.su/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040401)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050700)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050701)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050700)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013051001)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013060401)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040900)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050300)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013041500)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050801)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013053101)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050600)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013041500)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050801)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040400)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050801)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013060401)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013040500)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013041500)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050600)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013050801)
Jun 14 14:46:12 named[5829]: zone xxxxxx.ru/IN: sending notifies (serial 2013060401)
Jun 14 14:46:22 watchdog[5802]: Checking DNS
Jun 14 14:46:22 watchdog[5802]: DNS done (OK)
Jun 14 14:46:27 named[5829]: shutting down
...
```

Comment: Check this Q: http://serverfault.com/questions/345911/how-do-you-open-up-debug-logging-for-bind-on-ubuntu for advice on BIND debugging

Comment: Can you post the `/var/log/messages` and the `dmesg` command output during this time?

Answer (score 1):

named (BIND?) is stopping cleanly, indicating that something stopped it.  Possibly this might be someone typing commands or a cronjob stopping it, but it may also be watchdog erroneously assuming it is down and restarting it.

Comment: I'll try to stop dns monitoring.